# Name the clusters based on an attribute in kmeans algorithm

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka, k-means

I'm using the kmeans algorithm to classify my instances into different groups. I wrote a simple code in java that takes in the arff file and each instance is classified into a different cluster, where the number of clusters is given by me initially.

My output is generated in this format:

```
Instance 0-> Cluster 1
Instance 1-> Cluster 3      etc
```

Is there any way in which I can give the clusters names based on a single attribute?

Suppose my arff file is:

```
@relation links        
@attribute num1 numeric        
@attribute num2 numeric        
@attribute num3 numeric        
@attribute data string    

@data

0,0,5,a    
1,0,0,b    
1,0,0,a    
1,1,0,a etc
```

I want my clusters to be formed using these attributes and names based on the data attribute

So output should be:

```
Instance 0-. cluster a    
Instance 1-> cluster b
```

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: So your data is pre-clustered? Why use k-means then?

Comment: No it's not pre clustered. Nominal values are ignored during cluster formation. I want to cluster based on numerica attributes and name the clusters based on the nominal one. Its like this, suppose i have 20 instances with either a or b attribute and 2 clusters formed, in cluster 1 and 2: we see whether a or b has the highest number of instances and accordingly name it that.

Comment: ah I see. In that case your best bet is to post-process; run through the instances of each cluster after processing and count the number of each type.

Comment: Thanks was planning on doing that! Was wondering if there was any other method! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to mix everything into one process.

Data-mining is naturally a multi-step process. Some of the important steps are **pre- and postprocessing**.

Looks like you want to post-process your data, and report the most common label for each cluster.